# PDF Generate dynamically in android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

In My Pdf file data comes from server. so in every row not predeclared number of column and it's size mines width.
In every row whatever will come from server images or text.
i have tried using with a table and paragraph,chunks too with droidtext lib. but not got exactly result as i want.
how to set each column padding from parent document left side mines each column should start at zero(0) y axis. 
here my data comes row wise from top 
so in first row 2 data here anybody have idea plz help me. for solving this.
here post an image which is result i want and format my data as same ,
thanks in advance. 
[image]

Comment: if you are not happy with the official APIs just use a third part library.

Comment: here not the problem with any API or etc libraries      i need just output like as same display in image.